# React Native DOM

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to open a external site and access changes to its page elements? Except webView, because as far as I understand, this is the same iframe, and it can be blocked.
For example, you need to change the border color of the Yandex search bar. In electron, you can simply create a js file with the string document.querySelector("body > div.yandex-search.grid > form > table").style.borderColor="red" and add it to preload.